# Very basic SignalR Authentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication, signalr

I'm making a very basic client using SignalR where the user has a login screen. It doesn't even require a password, **only the username** to identify the user. They are free to choose their identity. At the moment I'm using a "Login" Hub to handle the login request, passing the username to it. (The client is a Windows Phone 8 application that communicates with the server using Hubs ONLY).
After this, I want **every** Hub to be able to identify this user (the information should be shared among all the Hubs) and to OPEN a group to the user to communicate with it.

The thing is that I don't know how to deal with this scenario, because I really don't use any of the built-in authentication methods.

I'm really confused because I don't know if I have to use the Hub.Context to set some information or what.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Getting Started tutorial does exactly this.

If there's no authentication, and the users choose their identities, why not just have the username be part of every packet that the client sends?